# Returning struct from function causes memory corruption

Tags: c, ffmpeg

I'm trying to return a FFmpeg AVDictionary struct from one function to another. I wrote the following two functions:

```
int get_p_metadata(State **ps, AVDictionary *metadata) {
    printf("get_p_metadata\n");

    State *state = *ps;

    if (!state || !state->pFormatCtx) {
        return FAILURE;
    }

    metadata = NULL;
    av_dict_copy(&metadata, state->pFormatCtx->metadata, 0);

    printf("count in get_p_metadata %d\n", metadata->count);

    return SUCCESS;
}

int get_metadata(State **ps) {
    printf("get_metadata\n");

    AVDictionary m;
    get_p_metadata(ps, &m);
    printf("count in get_metadata %d\n", (&m)->count);

    return SUCCESS;
}
```

The code compiles and runs however when I call the `get_metadata` function the generated output is:

```
count in get_p_metadata 12
count in get_metadata 2073109240
```

Can someone explain why the value of `count` changes from 12 to a random value every time I run this code? Why isn't the value of 12 retained once the `get_p_metadata` function returns? How would I fix this?

**UPDATE**:

This solution worked (Thanks to Cornstalks for actually reading the FFmpeg documentation and 
linkdd for the answer):

```
int get_p_metadata (State **ps, AVDictionary **metadata) {
    printf("get_p_metadata\n");

    State *state = *ps;

    if (!state || !state->pFormatCtx) {
        return FAILURE;
    }

    av_dict_copy(metadata, state->pFormatCtx->metadata, 0);

    return SUCCESS;
}

int get_metadata(State **ps, AVDictionary *metadata) {
    printf("get_metadata\n");

    AVDictionary *m = NULL;
    get_p_metadata (ps, &m);
    printf("count in get_metadata %d\n", m->count);

    return SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Why are you setting metadata parameter to null via `metadata = NULL;`?

Comment: Just a guess, buffer overrun.

Comment: William, will you try my answer and let me know if it worked? Try `memset`ing the dictionary's memory to zero, then passing it in. I believe the `memset` is necessary, but if my answer is wrong I'll delete it.

Comment: Cornstalks, I think linkdd's answer is the best approach. If you can go ahead and delete yours I would appreciate it (as to not clutter up the question). Thanks again for your help despite most of the other people bashing your for actually knowing what you were talking about.

Comment: Sure, I'll do that, but you should be aware that you need to call [`av_dict_free()`](http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/group__lavu__dict.html#ga1bafd682b1fbb90e48a4cc3814b820f7) when you're done; otherwise you'll leak memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, in your `get_p_metadata()` you have an argument `AVDictionary *metadata`.

You can consider it as a local variable in `get_p_metadata()`.
So, `&metadata` will refer to the local variable, and not your `m` variable in `get_metadata()`.

At the beginning of `get_p_metadata()`, `metadata` is set to the address of `m`, then you reset it to NULL.

You should try the following :

```
int get_metadata (State **ps)
{
    AVDictionary *m = NULL;
    get_p_metadata (ps, &m);
    av_dict_free (&m);
    return SUCCESS;
}

int get_p_metadata (State **ps, AVDictionary **metadata)
{
    /* ... */

    av_dict_copy (metadata, state->pFormatCtx->metadata, 0);

    /* ... */
}
```

This way, `av_dict_copy()` will allocate memory for your `AVDictionary` if `*metadata` is `NULL`, which is its inital value now.

Finally `av_dict_free()` will release the memory used by your dictionary.

Comment: This leaks memory, though.

Comment: Only if you don't free ``m`` in ``get_metadata()``, which should be done.

Comment: Indeed, but this answer or code don't mention that. You should use, or at the very least mention, `av_dict_free()`.

Answer (score 2):

You get different answers from the two statements because they are printing fields of different objects.  Although `get_metadata()` passes `&m` to `get_p_metadata()`, that function completely ignores the value passed, and reassigns the parameter value to `NULL`.  Frankly, I'm surprised you don't get a segfault.

I suppose your objective in setting `metadata = NULL` is to get a new metadata object created, but there is no connection between the local variable receiving the pointer to that new metadata object and the argument passed to the function.

Perhaps you want

```
int get_p_metadata(State **ps, AVDictionary **metadata) {
    ...
}
```

and

```
int get_metadata(State **ps) {
    printf("get_metadata\n");

    AVDictionary *m;
    get_p_metadata(ps, &m);
    printf("count in get_metadata %d\n", m->count);

    // NOTE: *m was dynamically allocated and needs to be cleaned up or returned

    return SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: That leaks memory, FYI.

Comment: Yes, it leaks memory.  The `get_metadata()` function must clean up the `AVDictionary` created by `get_p_metadata()`, or else provide it to its caller.  There is no getting around this if `av_dict_copy()` dynamically allocates the needed memory as the OP requested it to do in his original code.  The cleanup is left as an exercise ....  :-)

Comment: Sure, but I think you should add a noticeable comment after the `printf` that makes it very clear to the OP that they need to clean up. Otherwise, it's something that is easy to overlook.

Comment: Fair enough, @Cornstalks.  Added such a comment as you suggest.

Answer (score 1):

According to the declaration of  [av_dict_copy](http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/group__lavu__dict.html#ga6dabaab2d8a53674db6ffd5ac8de3d9f): the first parameter "dst" is a pointer to a pointer to a AVDictionary struct. If *dst is NULL, this function will allocate a struct for you and put it in *dst

For you code, you should not assign "metadata" to NULL as it already points to a AVDictionary struct, then it should be  fine.

If the metedata is NULL, it means av_dict_copy creates a new AVDictionary struct and changes the values  in it, while the struct defined in get_metadata(State **ps) remains unchanged, so you get the arbitrary vaules.

Comment: Sorry, but that didn't work. If I don't set the metadata variable to NULL the code produces a segfault.

Comment: it caused by "AVDictionary m" in function get_metadata(State **ps) not initialized as this struct contains pointers, try "AVDictionary m = {0}"

Answer (score -1):

What is the great sense in these statements?!

```
metadata = NULL;
av_dict_copy(&metadata, state->pFormatCtx->metadata, 0);
```

If you passed pointer to object `m` as an argument to the second function

```
AVDictionary m;
get_p_metadata(ps, &m);
```

then it seems you are going to use its value or the object itself. Otherwise there is no sense to pass the pointer.

Comment: [Maybe the documentation can shed some light](http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/group__lavu__dict.html#ga6dabaab2d8a53674db6ffd5ac8de3d9f): `If *dst is NULL, this function will allocate a struct for you and put it in *dst`

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. The first statement initializes the variable to null, the second one copies entries from one AVDictionary struct into another.

Comment: @Cornstalks. You obviously know what you are talking about. It seems some of the other people on here don't know how to read documentation. Also, if I don't set the metadata variable to NULL the code produces a segfault. Any ideas?

Comment: @William Seemann You declared object AVDictionary m; then pass address of it to the second function. And in the second function you set this address to NULL. What is the sense in this case to pass pointer to the object?!

Answer (score -1):

this code deosnt make sense

```
  metadata = NULL;
    av_dict_copy(&metadata, state->pFormatCtx->metadata, 0);
```

you passed in a pointer of a metadata object that I suppose was to be updated. Now you set that pointer to null, the call a function that updates that pointer. Since we cant see your other functions its hard to know what you intend so I cant suggest a fix

Comment: [It does make sense!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27824113/c-c-returning-struct-from-function-causes-memory-corruption#comment44054273_27824201)

Comment: no it doesnt - why pass in a pointer that is to be ignored. The calling code (get_metadata) seems to be expecting its m object to be updated. If the intent is that get_p_metadata allocates a structure then it should accept a AVDictionary  ** as param

Answer (score -1):

You are setting `metadata` to be a null pointer, before calling `av_dict_copy`. I wonder why that even works, and presume that `av_dict_copy` does something different than you expected (i.e. set a value to the AVDictionary*, whose adress is passed as the first argument). Either way, you lost your connection to your local `AVDictionary m` there and 2073109240 is just some random value in memory.